# Is there any way to see logs when application is running on device using testflight?

Tags: objective-c, logging, ios6, testflight

I want to see logs from application when it is running on tester's device. 
So, device is not connected to MAC.
I use following code to control that DLog() statement will log only when app is in DEBUG mode.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
#define ALog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Now, I want to test whether DLog() logs when running in testflight or not(DEBUG is disabled). So how can I see logs?

Note : 1) I tried setting DEBUG in preprocessor macros. That did not work so now I want to try with testflight.
2) Using testflight SDK will not work because to see logs they use `#define NSLog TFLog`, whereas I use ALog() and DLog().

Comment: do you want to see these logs being generated in real time (as the user is using them?) or do you expect these logs to be uploaded through TestFlight or?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I don't mind to see them any how or any time. I just want to see whether DLog() was printed or not.

Comment: Why not have your "`ALog`" and/or "`Dlog`" map to "`TFLog`"?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Because they are already mapped to NSLog.

Comment: You would either need to have the user submit their ASL (Apple System Log, formerly syslog), or their console log (debug output).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I mapped `Alog` and `Dlog` to `TFLog` and could see  log details from xcode organizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your `NSLog()`s in your device's crach log when you plug your iphone to your mac.

Just go to the organiser in xcode, select the devices tab, expand your device's information and select Device Logs. Find the name of your process (app),   click it, and there you'll find your `NSLogs()`s.

Comment: I already used xcode organizer 2 days back but as I did not post my own answer before you +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Late response but for future searchs:

You can use `console.app` (cmd+space and search for console) app and attach it to phone your app is currently running - then you can see all logs from device ;) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to have the user submit their ASL (Apple System Log, formerly syslog), or their console log (debug output). Or you can build an internal logging system which stores the output to a local file which you can have the user submit to you by either email or http post.